# Intersection of two dataframes without iteration

Tags: python, pandas

So I have two df's

Number one:

```
    Latitude    Longitude   Area
0   -25.66026   28.0914     HappyPlace
1   -25.67923   28.10525    SadPlace
2   -30.68456   19.21694    AveragePlace
3   -30.12345   22.34256    CoolPlace
4   -15.12546   17.12365    BadPlace
```

Number two:

```
    Latitude    Longitude   Population
0   -25.66026   28.0914     5000
1   -25.14568   28.10525    1750
2   -30.68456   19.21694    6000
3   -30.65375   22.34256    8000
4   -15.90458   17.12365    5600
```

I want to get the places that have the same latitude / longitude, so i know the population. **Most importantly I just need the intersections** for my real project

resulting df:

```
    Latitude    Longitude   Area
0   -25.66026   28.0914     HappyPlace
2   -30.68456   19.21694    AveragePlace
```

I've tried:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['LATITUDE'], how='inner')
```

Not working returns strange df

```
set(df1['LATITUDE']).intersection(set(df2['LATITUDE'))
df1[(df1['LATITUDE'] == df2['LATITUDE'])]
df1.where(df1.LATITUDE == df2.LATITUDE)
```

All return ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

(Actual Df's very very large, both columns are floats)

Comment: You want: `df1[df1['LATITUDE'].isin(df2['LATITUDE'])]`

Comment: Thanks that works, but can anyone explain why pd.merge() didnt work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.merge()` fails with a `KeyError` because `LATITUDE` is the wrong key.

The following MCVE works as expected.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
print(pd.__version__)

df1_string = """-25.66026   28.0914     HappyPlace
-25.67923   28.10525    SadPlace
-30.68456   19.21694    AveragePlace
-30.12345   22.34256    CoolPlace
-15.12546   17.12365    BadPlace"""

df2_string = """-25.66026   28.0914     5000
-25.14568   28.10525    1750
-30.68456   19.21694    6000
-30.65375   22.34256    8000
-15.90458   17.12365    5600"""

df1 = pd.DataFrame([x.split() for x in df1_string.split('\n')], columns=['Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Population'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([x.split() for x in df2_string.split('\n')], columns=['Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Population'])
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Latitude'], how='inner')
print(set(df1['Latitude']).intersection(set(df2['Latitude'])))
print(df1[(df1['Latitude'] == df2['Latitude'])])
print(df1.where(df1.Latitude == df2.Latitude))

print(result)
```

produces

```
0.24.2
{'-25.66026', '-30.68456'}
    Latitude Longitude    Population
0  -25.66026   28.0914    HappyPlace
2  -30.68456  19.21694  AveragePlace
    Latitude Longitude    Population
0  -25.66026   28.0914    HappyPlace
1        NaN       NaN           NaN
2  -30.68456  19.21694  AveragePlace
3        NaN       NaN           NaN
4        NaN       NaN           NaN
    Latitude Longitude_x  Population_x Longitude_y Population_y
0  -25.66026     28.0914    HappyPlace     28.0914         5000
1  -30.68456    19.21694  AveragePlace    19.21694         6000
```